# Retrieve custom http header in AuthorizeAttribute class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have added a custom header to a HTTP response using an ActionFilter attribute class and that works fine.

Am now trying to retrieve the value of this header in AuthorizeAttribute class but i cant get it, it returns null each time.

```
protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {
            var request = httpContext.Request;


            // extract from the htpp headers collection
            const string TokenUrlIdHeader = "UrlTokenId";
            string tokenUrlIdToValidate = request.Headers.Get(TokenUrlIdHeader);

            if (TokenGenerator.IsValidUrlToken(tokenUrlIdToValidate)) return true;


            return false;
        }
```

Is there something i'm missing?

Thanks

Comment: Do you assume that browser will send back a header in request that you have added to response? It doesn't work that way. You probably want to use Cookies here.

Comment: aah... yes sorry.. my head is slow today.. thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 0):

Answer provided by tpeczek

> Do you assume that browser will send back a header in request that you
>   have added to response? It doesn't work that way. You probably want to
>   use Cookies here